# Remove column by doctrine mapping inheritance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-sonata

What I want to do is to optimize my database by removing unnecessary fields from ProductTable.

My application is based on Sonata E-commerce. I want to remove the "shortDescription" field from the Product entity. Mapping  was defined in vendor so i can't easily remove the field.

I tried:

```
       <attribute-override name="rawShortDescription">
            <field />
        </attribute-override>
```

And it doesnt work.

In doctrine documentation, it is written that there is no possible way to override column type. Does that mean that I can't remove field?

Is it possible to remove field defined in vendor?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, do you have any update about that? I just created an other thread for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917844/remove-mapped-doctrine-field-of-parentclass-in-symfony-fosuserbundle

Comment: I just leave it. I didn't find solution

Comment: Have a look at my question i answered it