# Remove mapped doctrine field of parentclass in Symfony [FOSUserBundle]

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, symfony

How is it possible to remove a field that got inherited as doctrine column from mapping?

Example:

In FosUserBundle, I don't need some of the columns (e.g. salt, expiresAt...) within my User class. How can I tell symfony/doctrine to not map this column anymore to the database / remove it from the mapping? I know how to "reconfigure" the columns by using @AttributeOverride, but how can I completly remove a field from the mapping?

Regards.

Comment: If you remove the salt field why using FOSUser you can have a simple form login based on symfony security system. also you can't inherit parts of FOSUser entity.

Comment: This argument is weak and false, using bcrypt does not require a salt and is recommended for fos anyway. The reason why someone should use fos userbundle is not due to the fields in the entity, but due to nice features like Provider, user manager rtc

Comment: You could always fork the repository and customise it to fit your individual use case. That may mean more work in the future than just ignoring some fields on your database. Another option could be to use your own mapping (added to the config in `doctrine.orm.mappings.FOSUserBundle` - for the short config - see http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#full-default-configuration) and set defaults for the unused FOSUserBundle fields in your `__construct` where necessary. This, again, may also be more work than necessary.

Comment: I decided and already implemented an own "user management" and removed fosuserbundle. For a new project, I would recommend using fos as it is, but when you need to rely on structures that already exist and you are not allowed to change them (because in my case there is also a Windows service running on the same database) then you need to implement your own (which is btw described in the docs)

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much all default properties of the FOSUB User entity are mandatory to make the bundle working as expected.

The fields you given (salt, expiresAt) are related to the security, as the most part of the User properties.

Remove one of them may have side effects in your user management.

Also, you can't [Selectively inherit parts of an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214005/selectively-inherit-parts-of-an-entity).

Comment: Ok, so I need to accept some fields that I won't need to use and be aware that I need to check where these fields that I don't use would have been required

Comment: Most of those fields are only used for security and are mandatory for every user provider. I already lookjed at all default fields and I saw they are always called somewhere. You can see the definition of most of them in the [model](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php)  and how they are used in the [UserManipulator](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Util/UserManipulator.php).